# PHP top projects system

Tags: php

Basically I have a website where user vote on projects posted by users or "Support" everytime a user clicks the support button, it goes into a table and stores 3 things, a normal auto increment identifier, the user_id that 'supported' it and the project id they supported.  Now everyday we want to display 'Top projects' on the homepage.  This will my guess be done with a php script and a cron job.  I can't really think of how to query the database properly to determine X amount of top projects. (Most likely 5 or 10)  Iv'e thought about this for a while, but I can't think of an answer.  Any ideas/answers help alot!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your going to have to add a time stamp of one sort or another to that database. So you can query by the day from midnight to 11:59p. I'd say `datetime` format ie: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (its in 24 hour format)

From that if handled correctly you could do something like

```
<?php
$todayMidnight = date('Y-m-d'). ' 00:00:00';
$todayLastMin = date('Y-m-d'). ' 23:59:59';
$result = mysql_query("select * from the_table where the_Time BETWEEN $todayMidnight AND $todayLastMin LIMIT 10 order by the_count");
?>
```

Comment: Well, the ratings are stored in a separate DB with the project id, so users can't rate a project more than once...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you have an SQL database table called `votesTable` with a field `numberOfVotes`.

Without a cron-job or such, you might run this **MySQL-query**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM votesTable
  ORDER BY votesTable.numberOfVotes DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

to retrieve the to **top 10 vote entries**.

This [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAfY4HeDd_Q) *PHP Tutorial: Simple Rating / Voting System [part 01]* may help ([tutorial author's page](http://betterphp.co.uk/tutorials.html)).